# Entity Framework Core: Avoid Recursive Constructor Calls in the Modeling Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

In my application I eventually want to have two views, A and B. View A will show A objects and their related B objects. View B will show B objects and their related A objects. **I need to get data in from the data layer to the modeling layer going both ways from A to B, and vice versa. Unfortunately, it seems to cause recursive constructor calls, and I don’t see any way to avoid this issue.** I’d rather not use a tool like Automapper. How to I get the data into the model going both ways, while avoiding recursive constructor calls?

- In the database I have a one-to-many relationship between A and B.
- A has many B's
- B has one A

I scaffolded in the Context and Data classes from the database and it generated these classes in the data layer:

- Data.MyDatabaseNameContext
- Data.A
- Data.B

I didn’t make any changes to the above scaffolded classes and I’m confident that they scaffolded in correctly.

In I create 2 new View Models for A and B, then initialize their properties in the constructors:

View Model for A:

```
public class A
{
    public readonly Data.A _A;

    public Guid AId { get; set; }

    public List<Models.B> Bs { get; set; }

    // Inside this constructor a new B object is always made
    public A(A dbobject)
    {
        _A = dbobject;

        Bs = new List<B>();

        foreach (var item in dbobject.B)
        {
            B.Add(new B(item));
        }
    }
}
```

View Model For B:

```
public class B
{
    public readonly Data.B _B;

    public Guid BId { get; set; }
    public Guid AId { get; set; }

    public Models.A A { get; set; }

    // inside this constructor a new A object is always made, thus causing the recursion
    public B(B dbobject)
    {
        _B = dbobject;

        A.Id = dbobject.AId

        this.A = new A(dbobject.A)
    }
}
```

And in the repository:

```
public interface IARepository {

    Task<A> A(Guid id);
    // Other CRUD signatures omitted
}

public class ARepository : IARepository 
{
    private readonly MyDatabaseNameContext _context;

    public ARepository(MyDatabaseNameContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public async Task<A> A(Guid id)
    {
        var a = await this._context.A.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(a => a.B)
            .Select(a => new A(a))
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        return a == null ? null : a;
    }
}

// OTHER CRUD METHODS OMITTED
```

And B has a similar IBRepository interface and IBRepository repository as above just with all the a's and b's swapped.

Comment: You don't need any of that. By using `AsNoTracking` you are loading detached entities and eager loading the related entities. just return "a" which will have all of it's "B" references set up. Also, `return a == null ? null : a` is just `return a`, it seems you are overthinking problems which is making unnecessary work for yourself.

Comment: You don't need any of that code to use EF Core and ViewModels. EF Core is already a high-level, domain repository: a multi-entity repository *and* unit-of-work. Mapping entity classes to viewmodel classes *assuming it's needed*, is as simple as `.Select(obj=>new MyOtherClass{PropA=obj.A,...})`. You could use AutoMapper to reduce the boilerplate code. If you don't want AutoMapper, you'll have to write that code yourself.

Comment: @Steve Py I understand that will get the data into the Entity Classes but that doesn't get the data into the View Model classes, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: *DON'T* use `.Select(a => new A(a))` though, unless you really want all properties. EF Core doesn't know what's hidden inside that constructor so it's forced to load all columns. A `Select()` that only selects the necessary properties is far better. That's what AutoMapper does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, ok I see now you have Data domain A and View Model A.. Probably worth naming these a bit more clearly like Customer and CustomerViewModel rather that Data.Customer and Model.Customer or such.

For a start, Repositories should normally be dealing with Entities, not ViewModels/DTOs. The Generic Repository pattern is an anti-pattern for EF as it severely limits the capabilities that EF can provide for features like Projection. The Repository pattern is still valuable for enabling things like unit testing, but I recommend treating the repository like a Controller in terms of it's scope where a Repository serves a Controller rather than having a repository per entity. The pattern I find helpful is to have repositories return `IQueryable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` or `T` or `Task` of either of those. This gives consumers full control to apply sorting, filtering, projection, pagination, etc.

However, if you want a Repository per ViewModel, that's not all that much different, it's better than Repository per Entity provided your ViewModels will explicitly serve the needs of the view, and aren't just a straight copy of the entity.

When projecting via EF you don't need to eager load, just leverage `Select`:

```
public async Task<AViewModel> GetAViewModel(Guid id)
{
    var a = await this._context.A
        .Select(a => new AViewModel
        {
            // copy values from a -> viewModel properties
            Bs = a.Bs.Select(b => new BViewModel
            {
                // copy values from b -> viewModel
            }).ToList()
        }).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    return a;
}
```

I wouldn't be reluctant to learn Automapper as this is an extremely powerful tool for projection via it's `ProjectTo` method. You set up the configuration either once for all view models, or on an as-needed basis, then this simplifies to:

```
public async Task<AViewModel> GetAViewModel(Guid id)
{
    var a = await this._context.A
        .ProjectTo<AViewModel>(_config)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    return a;
}
```

Where `_config` represents the mapping configuration that defines how an A becomes an AViewModel and any dependent relations for the ViewModel (I.e. B -> BViewModel, etc.)